# string value ^[A-E] in php

Tags: php

Is it okay to set a string lets say `$expression='^[A-E]'` in php?

I'm trying to pass it as a regular expression but I find that its being used as something messed up like `%5E%5BA-E%5D`

Comment: Are you passing it as user input (e.g: in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's been passed through a URL.

You can decode that to get the string you want using [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been URL encoded, which shouldn't happen. You might get a better answer if you post more of your code.